# Move div with keyboard (requestAnimationFrame not working)

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS, but want to write Snake game. In process stuck with a problem: I'm using requestAnimationFrame for animating div, everything works( my div is moving ), but when I'm started to write switch statment for changing direction my code breaks. 
 In result I can achive  one of the two: moving my div with requestAnimationFrame without having opportunity to change direction  with keybord arrow,  or move and change direction but without animation if i stop pressing the keybord arrow. Can somebody help me to combine animation with keybord manipulation?

Here is my code:

```
 // field object
  var fieldObj = {
      field: document.getElementById( "field" ),
      w: 480,
      h: 580
  },
 snakeObj = {
     snake: document.getElementById( "snake" ),
     p: { 
        x: 0, // position x 
        y: 0  // position y
     },
     v: {
        x: 2, // velocity( here you can change speed)
        y: 2
     },
 update: function( event ) {
       event = event || window.event;
       switch( event.keyCode ) {
        case 40:
           this.p.x += this.v.x;
           break;
        case 38:
           this.p.x -= this.v.x;
           break;
        case 39:
           this.p.y += this.v.y;
           break;
        case 37:
           this.p.y -= this.v.y;
           break;
      }
     this.snake.style.top = this.p.x + "px";
     this.snake.style.left = this.p.y + "px"
  }
}

window.addEventListener('keydown', function gameLoop() {
    snakeObj.update();
    requestAnimationFrame( gameLoop );
 }, false);
```

Codepen of problem( here div movung but without opportunity to manipulation ) http://codepen.io/Kuzyo/pen/esFbf 
Thanks for every help

With the help, I achieved that when I press left div moves left, than I can switch direction to right, but if I want him to move left again he continuing moves to right. The same with up and down.

Here is updated code: http://codepen.io/Kuzyo/pen/esFbf

Comment: You're searching for the [keydown keyboard event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent).

Comment: Your `keydown` and `keyup` events should only set some switches as true, but the update should be independent of them and always be called in the `requestAnimationFrame()`. The update function then reads the switches and does the necessary. So, the movement increments should be performed in the update, which is called every frame, not in keydown.

Comment: @Broxzier I know, I can move, but if I stopped to pressing key my div stops too, but I want that div  moves further

Comment: @kuzyoy Then safe the key you're pressing in a variable and read that one instead of the actual keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, call your update after requesting an animation frame, this gives you slightly smoother times.

```
//declare and start the game loop
(function gameLoop(){
  requestAnimFrame(gameLoop);
  snakeObj.update();
})();
```

We now have set up our animation frame. Which means `update()` will be called every frame, regardless of your key events. Now, all we have to do is set some switches in the key events.

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function() {

    switch( event.keyCode ) {
    case 40:
       snakeObj.keys.left = true;
       break;

    ...

    }
}, false);
```

You also need a `keyup` event to set the flags as false. On update, just read the key data and move. Something like:

```
this.update() {

    //read the keys and move accordingly
    if( this.keys.left ) {
       this.p.x -= 5;
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrei. Almost, but no more than two keypress http://codepen.io/Kuzyo/pen/esFbf. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: You are still doing it wrong! If you call `update()` in the `keydown` event handler function, it will only be called **when you press a key**. Update should always happen, regardless if you press any keys or not! Your game loop needs to be implemented independently, like I explained at the very top. Follow my instructions

Comment: I added console.log to gameLoop and it showing that gameLoop and as result my update() running independently. Thanks for your helphttp://codepen.io/Kuzyo/pen/esFbf

Comment: Thanks @ Andrei Nemes everything works, but before seting the direction snakeObj.keys.left = true; I need to cansel previos to false for example snakeObj.keys.r = false;

Comment: No, you need to have a `keyup` event handler that sets them to false. Also, as a future improvement, you could use vectors to determine directions. If left is -1 and right is 1 both key presses result in 0, which is not a direction change, but pressing them individually results in a change.